# Inner View comes outside from outer View in Constraint Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-constraintlayout

I am using `ConstraintLayout` to design one complex view which should look good in all devices irrespective of their size. At centre one `ImageView1` is positioned whose width is set as `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6"` & height is `0dp`. One another `ImageView2` is placed inside layout whose `Start` & `End` are constrained to `Start` & `End` of `ImageView1` and `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.4"`. Based on the above constraint ideal working is, even though screen size changed the `ImageView1` will occupy `0.6%` part of screen and `ImageView2` will occupy `0.4%`. But the `ImageView2` on smaller size devices comes out of `ImageView1`. Any tips & help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try to use the same image in both views - it might be a resolution thing

Comment: Can you post the XML?